# Placing leaflet controls outside map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My requirement is to create N type of markers in leaflet. The list is huge that can not be fit in map area.

**I want something similar to this :** 
http://blog.georepublic.info/2012/leaflet-example-with-wfs-t/  
There is some problem in the above given example that while zooming in the marker moves from their original position. 
 Please suggest any fix for this or any other alternative to place the controls outside the map like this example.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186131/placing-controls-outside-map-container-with-leaflet may help

Answer (score 2):

Is it OK to put your controls in sidebar?
https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2

Answer (score 0):

Simple possible way i have used:

Add below html tag, where you want move the leaflet controls:

```
<div id="custom-map-controls"></div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var newParent = document.getElementById('custom-map-controls');
        var oldParent = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-top leaflet-right")

        while (oldParent[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
            newParent.appendChild(oldParent[0].childNodes[0]);
        }
 });
```